# Excel VBAからPython関数を実行する際のデバッグ方法について

Tags: python3, vba, excel, pycharm

https://fastclassinfo.com/entry/run_python_from_vba/#2-BPython
あたりを参考に、Excel VBA から、python関数を呼び出そうとしています。
この通りにやったところ、ごく小規模なPythonプログラムは動かせるようになりました。（Pythonから、エクセルシートにデータを書き込むなど）

このPython側の関数をデバッグする方法はあるのでしょうか？
１．pyファイル内のソースで、ブレークを張ったり、ステップ実行したりする方法
２．print文で出力したものをExcel(VBA)側で受け取る方法

［環境］
PyCharm 2021.3.1 (Community Edition)
Python 3.8.5

Windows 10 Home(21H2 64bit)
Excel バージョン 2112

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: デバッグを行うのは VBA の実行中に Excel で、と言うことでしょうか？ (もしそうなら PyCham はあまり関係なさそうです)

Comment: cubickさん、ありがとうございます。

＞デバッグを行うのは VBA の実行中に Excel で、と言うことでしょうか？ 

実行中での話ですが、Excel以外の方法があればそれでも良いと思っています。
PyChamとうまい具合に連携する方法でもあれば、、、と思ったのですが、やっぱりないですかね。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかもしれません。[How to call python script on excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18135551/9014308), [pdb --- Python デバッガ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/pdb.html), [breakpoint(*args, **kws)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) Pythonスクリプトを実行するのにデバッガ(`pdb`)のパラメータとして指定してみては？ ただし1.と2.を同時に行うのは難しいのでは？ またPyCharmはIDEなのでそうした使い方は出来なさそうな感じです。

Comment: 回答をくださった皆さん、ありがとうございます。あまり深追いするのはやめておきます。